# When to use :: and when to use # in documentation

Tags: php, documentation

I've seen both used in documentation of a PHP library (seemingly interchangeably) and was wondering if there's a method to the madness and a time when each *should* be used? (Or if they mean something different, a nuance which I've therefore missed in the documentation)

Examples:

```
ClassName#foo()  // a method
ClassName::bar() // a method
ClassName::baz   // a property
```

I've not (yet) seen anybody try to use `ClassName#qux` for a property but perhaps that's possible too!

Hopefully this thread will help to set people on the straight and narrow!

Thanks in advance

P.S. it's hard searching Google for this. "#" = "hash" = "pound" and "::" = "double colon" = "T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM"... and "hash" means something all of its own too, of course.

Edit: A further question is whether it is normal/correct to document properties and variables as `ClassName::foo` or `ClassName::$foo` (i.e. with or without a leading $)

Comment: I usually use `::`. php documentation uses it too. So, _in my opinion_. it's better choice. This question is opinion based.

Comment: Hash is confusing with comments in my opinion, so I prefer ::, but after all , it's an opinion based choice.

Comment: Can you provide a link to PHP documentation using the `#` method that you're describing? Or is this something you've seen only in a specific app/framework? I've never seen it personally

Comment: I have always used :: as well, I'm just trying to understand why somebody would (and if I should) use # instead!

Comment: There are some examples here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html

Comment: @caponica I can't see `#` being used in actual code docs on that page, just in the body text; am I missing something? If not, it looks like that's just how doctrine have decided to write their documentation.

Comment: Even for PHP, it's perverse, which is saying a lot. Don't ever do it in any context.

Comment: That's correct. The # is not used in code, it's just in documentation.

Comment: @AaronMiller - I think yours is the best answer so far :)

Comment: @caponica Converted to a proper answer, just for grins. :)

Comment: There's nothing on comments in the unofficial coding standards repo ([PHP-fig::fig-standards](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards)), but I'd say that if ever they get round to normalizing comments, they'd probably prefer `::` over `#`, like most human beings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even for PHP, it's perverse, which is saying a lot. Don't ever do it in any context.

Comment: Well, I reckon 20 minutes is long enough for judge and jury on stack exchange. I'll accept Aaron's answer unless anybody comes up with an insight that the rest of the community seems to be lacking!

Answer (score 1):

It is probably to disambiguate between actual static methods which can literally be called with `Foo::bar()`, and *instance* methods which require an object instance, like `$foo->bar()`. That's the only sensible explanation I can think of, and it's not an official standard in any context that I'm aware of.

Comment: Well, I thought that might be the case but the examples on this page don't fit that description. E.g. ``EntityManager#find()`` requires an instance of EntityManager. And so does ``User::addReportedBug()``

Comment: So they're not consistent in their use, or some Ruby programmer was thinking in the wrong language when writing the documentation.

Comment: @deceze Wait, you can use `#` that way in Ruby? I've seen `"#{...}"` syntax for `eval` blocks in strings, and that's a filthy enough thing to be doing with your comment character, but never seen it used to introduce a class or instance method.

Comment: @Aaron No, but it's a thing in their documentation.